# Creating flood inundation map from watermark QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, hydrology

I have a high water elevation for a location and I want to subtract this elevation by the DEM raster to achieve a water depth raster, and I am not sure how to go about this.

I am assuming a constant water elevation across this location and want to create a rough flood inundation map with the water depths at each point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed the raster calculator. Here is what I put in the equation:

```
HWE - "DEM@1"
```

where:

- HWE = value of high water elevation at same vertical datum and units as DEM raster (e.g. 44)
- DEM = the file name of the DEM layer which I used

Comment: Well done.  Feel free to mark your answer as the solution.